# How do I access an animator with OnCollision in a script located on a different gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need it to where when OnCollision is invoked on the gameobject that is triggered, it will communicate to the animator on the other gameobject so it can start the animation.

I have this code right here:

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class SmallDoor : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Animator anim;
    
        void Start()
        {
            anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        }
    
        private void Update()
        {
        }
    
        private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            if (other.tag == "Player")
                anim.SetBool("DoorOpen", true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just run the animation from the same script like this...

```
private Animator anim;


void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}


private void Update()
{

}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
        other.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("DoorOpen", true);
}
```

But if you want to access the script on the object then try something like this...

On the other object's make sure that they have a public function like this

```
public void Function()
{
    //Insert code here
}
```

Then on the main object go ahead and

```
private Animator anim;


void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}


private void Update()
{

}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    other.GetComponent<InsertOtherScriptName>.Function();
    if (other.tag == "Player")
        anim.SetBool("DoorOpen", true);
}
```

> Make sure to change the "InsertOtherScriptName" and "Function()" with whatever you need/have.

Hope I could help